# How to use VBA to apply Auto Filter per month/year and add a value in another range based on the month/ Year filter

Tags: excel, vba

How can I use VBA to apply a filter in a column (per month/Yer) so the range corresponding to that date will receive value as Month-Yes in another column?

Or in this case, would be better to use if the value in the column named CreationDate is = Jan/2020 then range on column Month_Yr will be 01_2020.

Basic the VBA need to check dates on column A and if it writes only the month and year on column B.

Should I use the auto filter or Vlook?
Any ideas how can I get the result I need?

Comment: I really don't know if I completely understand your question. But if all you want is display the date in the format month_year in the next column and filter, have you tried a formula like `=TEXT(A2,"m\_yyyy")`?

Comment: Thank you. However, there will be a lot information in this case would be possible to use in VBA. `”sheet1.range(”B2”).formula= ” =TEXT(A2,"m_yyyy")” sheet1.range(”B2”).autofill sheet1 (”B2:B” & last row)”`

Comment: Or you can simply use `Sheet1.Range("B2:B" & last_row).Formula = "=TEXT(A2,""m_yyyy"")"`. Note the double double-quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your comments, you can use

```
With Sheet1.Range("B2:B" & last_row)
    .Formula = "=TEXT(A2,""m\_yyyy"")"
    ' I suggest you then delete the formulae
    .Value = .Value
End with
```

Note the way to add double quotes inside a string is to use 2 of them (i.e. escape it with another double quote), therefore the string `"=TEXT(A2,""m\_yyyy"")"` will result in the formula =TEXT(A2,"m\_yyyy").

Also note the underscore character has a special meaning in excel number formatting and therefore, if you want it displayed in the final string then you need to escape it with a backslash. (I know it looked like a typo in my comment above, but it is important)